# When to Use CSV from Web or Keeping Data in Xcode?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, csv

I do not believe this has been asked before so please be easy on me.

I plan to have a flashcard app that when pressing the "next" button, will cycle **randomly** through them. There will be different categories for different topics which will be accessed through a relative UIButton.

I could add all my data as code in Xcode of course, but the only issue is that when a new flashcard is created the user will have to update the App via App Store.

I have found bits and pieces of information regarding JSON and CSV files and pulling that data from an online source, however, with allowing the user to press a button to randomly cycle through what will be essentially TextViews, **I have hit a dead-end on finding if this is an effective option** or if there are better options. I also struggle to find information related to imported to Xcode, however, there is more than enough information on exporting from Xcode to CSV.

Thank You!

Comment: This sounds more like an app architecture question than an Xcode question per se, but it might helps to think about this from a user's perspective. Do you want the app to require an internet connection, or allow users to play offline? If the latter, then at some point, you will need to store some of the JSON/CSV files somewhere locally; in which case, there's nothing preventing you from going with a hybrid approach: include some base subjects with the app itself, but allow the app to also download new packs when an internet connection is present.

Comment: (At the very least, you may want to include _some_ data along with the app, so that if a user downloads your app but opens it up offline for the first time, they can interact with it in some way. Not all app do this — some games, for instance, require a download of game data on first launch, but for a smaller app, it may not be prohibitive to include that data with the app itself.)